# Sticky menu on click gets closed but opens after window scroll without clicking again

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a link that opens a menu, and then on window scroll past a certain point, it pins to the top of the screen. When you close it, and then scroll again, it just opens again and pins. I know why conceptually it's happening and tried a few things, but can't get it to work. Code below ( just the JS). Just need it to close and not reappear when you scroll. Thanks in advance and sorry if it's a stupid question.

HTML

```
<div class="feedback">Share For Feedback</div>
<div class="dropdown"> 
    <p>Share it !!!</p> 
    <span> 
        <a href="#" class="closedrop">X</a>
    </span>
    <div class="share-icon-holder"> 
        <span class="spr share-icon fb"> 1 </span>
        <span class="spr share-icon tw"> 2 </span>
        <span class="spr share-icon mail "> 3 </span>
        <span class="spr share-icon copy"> 4 </span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JQuery

```
function showSticky() {
var feedback = $('.feedback'),
dropdown = $('.dropdown'),
myloveitfirstrow = $('.my-love-it-product:first'),
closedrop = $('.closedrop'),
hasBeenClicked = false;

$(feedback).click(function () {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    $(dropdown).show();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var midheight = $(myloveitfirstrow).outerHeight(true),
        scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (scrollVal > midheight) {
            $(dropdown).css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'left': '0', 'display': 'block', 'z-index': '400', 'text-align': 'center', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100px' });
        } else {
            $(dropdown).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '50px', 'left': '-100px' });
        }
     });
 });

 $(closedrop).click(function () {
     hasBeenClicked = true;
     $(dropdown).hide();
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (scrollVal > midheight) {
    $(dropdown).css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'left': '0'/*, 'display': 'block'*/, 'z-index': '400', 'text-align': 'center', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100px' });
} else {
    $(dropdown).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '50px', 'left': '-100px' });
}
```

Does it still do it if you make the change above? I commented out `display: block`, which was being set as long as the position was fixed. That's going to make it show again.

Comment: Oh man, that works! Thanks! That was really a silly oversight on my part. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn off the scroll event when the menu is closed again. First, you might want to create a function that is called after a scroll event is triggered:

```
function scrollHandler() {
    // Add your code here
}
```

Enable the event after the user has opened the menu:

```
$(feedback).click(function () {
    $(dropdown).show();
    $(window).on('scroll', scrollHandler);
})
```

Finally, turn off the scroll event handler when the menu is closed again:

```
$(closedrop).click(function () {
    $(dropdown).hide();
    $(window).off('scroll', scrollHandler);
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. Very cool and didn't think about the off method. I like that approach, very clean. Thanks!